# Understanding C double formatter placeholder

Tags: c, printf, decimal, number-formatting

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
double x = 10.4, y;
int m = 2;
y = x / m;

printf("%.1f\n", y);//5.2
printf("%.1f\n", (double)(7 / 2)); //3.0, why not 3.5 ?
printf("%.1f\n", 3.5f);//3.5
// the last line prints 3.5,
// why its not rounding down to 3.0 ,as it did above ?
}
```

Can someone explain whats happening here ?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I will take a look at that one also,thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line `printf("%.1f\n", (double)(7 / 2));`, the order of operations is as follows:

1. `7/2 = 3`
2. `(double)3 = 3.0`
3. `printf("%.1f\n", 3.0);// Your problem becomes evident.`

To achieve the expected behaviour, change `(double)(7 / 2)` to `7.0 / 2`
(i.e., `printf("%.1f\n", 7.0 / 2);`then your code will correctly print `3.5`).

`7/2` divides two `ints`, thus automatically truncating the result to `3` as is the way with [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division). You then cast the result of the integer division to a `double` to produce `3.0`. All these troubles can be avoided if one of the numbers in a mathematical expression is a `double`, then the other is implicitly cast to a `double`, thus producing a `double` in the result.

Answer (score 3):

Change `printf("%.1f\n", (double)(7 / 2));` to `printf("%.1f\n", (double)(7.0 / 2));` to get the desired result. `7.0` makes the result to be double.